# Application not appearing after being installed

Tags: android, installation, appearance

I install an apk in my Android mobile but it doesn't appear in "Applications" section. I can see it through "Settings" -> "Applications Administrator" but I don't know how can I send it to "Applications" in order to be able to drag and drop the icon into my mobile desktop.

```
This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="principe.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19">
    </uses-sdk>
    <application
        android:name="principe.android.ApplicationContext"
        android:icon="@drawable/application_image"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="principe.android.MainDialogActivity"
            android:label="@string/application_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN_DIALOG"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You're likely missing the launcher `intent-filter` in your manifest. Please include the manifest in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:installLocation` directive in your manifest.

For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
   android:installLocation="internalOnly">
   ...
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   </intent-filter> 
</manifest>
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) for more info.

Comment: Same result. My application installs successfully replacing the last one I installed, but no icon on "Applications" menu. I can only see it through "Settings" but I am not able to launch it.

Comment: I have updated my answer above. This `android.intent.action.MAIN_DIALOG` should be this `android.intent.action.MAIN`. As far as I know, there's no `android.intent.action.MAIN DIALOG` action in Android

Comment: I understand what you were doing now. Happy coding!